# why the delimiter still show on missing values when paste is used in R

Tags: r

when I use the `paste()` to concatenate, for missing values we still get the delimiter, how to avoid the delimiter display when values are missing

```
CM <- data.frame(
   CONMED = c("ZOMIG","TYLENOL","CLAVULANIC ACID "),
   DOSE = c("5 mg"," ","62.5 mg"))

CM

CM$CONMEDOS <- paste(CM$CONMED,CM$DOSE,sep='/')
CM
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We could use a conditional statement.  The OP's 'DOSE' doesn't have missing values (`NA`), but it is showing blank or whitespaces (`" "`).  `paste` doesn't have an action to ignore those, so we can create a logical condition with `!=` or `nzchar` (It may be better to have missing values i.e. NA instead of `" "`)

```
i1 <- trimws(CM$DOSE) != ""
CM$CONMEDOS[i1] <- paste(CM$CONMED[i1],CM$DOSE[i1],sep='/')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ifelse` to choose either `"/"` or `""` should be used to concatenate two columns, e.g.,

```
transform(
  CM,
  CONMEDOS = paste0(CONMED, ifelse(DOSE == " ", "", "/"), DOSE)
)
```

- output

```
            CONMED    DOSE                 CONMEDOS
1            ZOMIG    5 mg               ZOMIG/5 mg
2          TYLENOL                         TYLENOL
3 CLAVULANIC ACID  62.5 mg CLAVULANIC ACID /62.5 mg
```